# Running Jetty on Port80 as non root user

Tags: java, jetty, root, port80

I found this out of date howto, does anybody know what replaced SetUIDServer? I'm using Jetty8

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/port80

Answer (score 0):

Look in the jetty-hightide distribution, it ships with the setuid setup in place for reference.

we just pushed this up today:

http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-hightide/8.1.2.v20120308/

cheers

Comment: Cool. What exactly is hightide?

Comment: Looks like this is a better solution.

http://67-23-9-112.static.slicehost.net/faq?s=300-HTTP&t=user80

Comment: @DouglasFerguson - The instructions in that page are also in the original page you linked to.

Comment: hightide is the jetty distribution coupled with some other artifacts that we did not want to bother passing through the eclipse IP verification process when we moved to eclipse.  those modules remain at codehaus and get included into the hightide release