# Is there a debian distribution for Jetty-Hightide 7 or 8?

Tags: jetty

I want to easily install Jetty on my Ubuntu server and have it listen on Port 80, but I don't want the webapp JVMs to run as root.  I saw this other question that points to how Jetty-Hightide is already set up to use the SetUID functionality but I would like to be able to download it as a deb package instead of a tarball file (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640533/running-jetty-on-port80-as-non-root-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/dist/jetty-deb/

those debs are based on hightide